# IJCADでのWMFファイルの作成方法

Tags: .net, ijcad

AUTOCADでWMFファイルを作成することはできるのですが、IJCADで実装する方法がわかりません。
ご教示いただけないでしょうか。
AUTOCADでWMFファイルを作成するプログラムは以下の通りです。

```
Function ImportWMF(FullPath As String, ptIns As Point3d, scale As Double) As String
    Dim doc As Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Document = 
                Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument

    Using doc.LockDocument()
        Dim acadDoc As Object = 
                Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.DocumentExtension.GetAcadDocument(doc)
        Try
            Dim obj As Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.AcadObject = acadDoc.Import(FullPath, ptIns.ToArray, scale)
            Return obj.Handle

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return String.Empty
        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

IJCADの.NET APIでは、Editor.CommandメソッドでWMFINコマンドを使用するとで、WMFを読み込めると思います。

```
Function ImportWMF(FullPath As String, ptIns As Point3d, scale As Double, rotated As Double) As String
    Dim doc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor
    ed.Command("WMFIN", FullPath, ptIns, scale, scale, rotated)
    Dim res As PromptSelectionResult = ed.SelectLast()
    If res.Status = PromptStatus.OK Then
        Return res.Value.GetObjectIds()(0).Handle.ToString()
    End If
    Return String.Empty
End Function
```